# How do i get the jar sign from java code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to display one my jar file name along with the signature(today's date) in the application.

```
Plugin name : a.b.c
Plugin id : a.b.c
version = 1.0.1_qualifier
```

The jar file name looks like this : a.b.c_1.0.1.20150724.jar

How do i get this whole info from java code.

Comment: What information do you have to start with? The `Bundle`? The `BundleContext`?

Comment: @greg-449 i did not get your question. Can you please be more eloborative.

Comment: I need you the elaborate as your question is very unclear. Is this code running in a plugin? If it is in a plugin are you asking for the details about the current plugin or some other plugin or what?

Comment: @greg-449 My code runs in a plugin and i want the details of the current plugin.

Comment: @greg-449 I want to display something similar to what we see in Eclipse - > Help -> About Eclipse SDK -> Installation Details - > Plugins tab

Comment: Yes but do you want that for the current plugin, some specific other plugin or for all plugins?

Comment: @greg-449 Only for the current plugin

Answer (score 0):

Get the `Bundle` for the current plugin:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

Get the plugin jar headers:

```
Dictionary<String, String> headers = bundle.getHeaders();
```

Get the name, id and version:

```
String name = Platform.getResourceString(bundle, headers.get("Bundle-Name"));
String id = bundle.getSymbolicName();
String version = headers.get("Bundle-Version");
```